# Gradle copy task is slow

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

My copy task is really simple. The source folder only contains one text file (2 KB), but the copy tasks needs nonetheless 300-700ms, although the task is most of the time up-to-date.

```
  task("copySomething", type: Copy) {
    String fileName = 'test.txt'
    File srcDir = file("folder/folder")

    if (!file("$srcDir/$fileName").exists()) {
      srcDir = file("folder/folder2")
    }

    include fileName
    from srcDir
    into "."
  }
```

I noticed that the destination dir plays a big role. If I change it to something else, then everything is as expected a lot faster. Why is this the case?

Comment: I was facing the same issue!

Comment: Did you fixed the issue?